# Audio restart on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

It appears that some solutions for older versions do not apply for Ubuntu disco

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/pulseaudio restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/pulseaudio: command not found
```

Also `sudo alsa force-reload` not solved the no sound problem. What should I do (beside reboot)?

Comment: Your haven't really asked a question.  There is no Ubuntu 19, nor Ubuntu Core 19 (a release that uses *yy* format instead of usual *yy.mm*).  Sysvinit was replaced by systemd years ago, and it doesn't exist in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Ubuntu Core 18 either.  If using a desktop, why not use "Pulse Audio Volume Control" and the *Configuration* tab (clicking profile off/on will reset) or use `pulseaudio`